# Controlling iOS Zoom settings

Tags: ios, iphone, unity-game-engine

I have a problem in my app where by when users have the iPhone Zoom settings toggled to ON:

Settings > General > Accesibility > Zoom > on

Some of the content within in the app becomes enlarged.

So my question is where can I find the settings to the Zoom options so I can resolve this issue?

Comment: I believe that is the intent of "zoom > on". Probably just need to adjust your storyboard with proper constraints.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you have been working on a large iPhone (or even iPad) when in the `Storyboard`. However, when this is displayed on a smaller screen, everything will look bigger.

Consider using constraints and previewing the application in Xcode.